# Three finger flick not working as expected

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, gestures, synaptics-touchpad

I've got a Lenovo y580 with both Windows 7 and Windows 8 installed.  When I first installed Windows 8, the three finger flick to go back or forward a page in an internet or file browser worked fine.  But now, when I three finger flick backwards, instead of going to the last page I was at, it goes to the very first page I accessed (like continually going back in my history until I cannot go back any further.) The same happens with forward click.

The flick works fine in my Windows 7 installation which makes me wonder if this a registry setting somewhere that got messed up?

There is no setting to control exactly what a three-finger flick does in the Synaptics driver that I can find.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed any additional drivers (like for a mouse, for instance)?

Comment: Not explicitly... I have the plug and play drivers for a logitech wireless mouse installed on both OSes though

Comment: Are they the drivers automatically installed by Windows?

Comment: Yep, installed automatically when you connect the wireless stick

Comment: I ended up fixing the problem by reinstalling the trackpad driver if anyone else has this problem.

Comment: ^ Make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing the problem by reinstalling the trackpad driver if anyone else has this problem.