# How to navigate web with 3-finger flick in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Synaptics trackpad that supported 3-finger flick for going backward or forward on the web.  But now in Windows 10, 3-finger flicks do some sort navigation between applications or folders or something.  Does anyone know how to reconfigure the 3-finger flick back to web browsing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three finger flick not working as expected](https://superuser.com/questions/546719/three-finger-flick-not-working-as-expected)